# Can't enter a negative number on iЩІ

Tags: ios, qt, qml

On Android, it works fine. For iOS, the minus sign is not displayed on the keyboard.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.3

TextField {
    placeholderText: qsTr("Enter price")
    inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhFormattedNumbersOnly
    inputValidator : DoubleValidator {
        bottom: -infinity
        decimals: 10
        notation: DoubleValidator.StandardNotation
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't run that code at all... `inputValidator` does not exist...

Comment: "inputValidator" - thanks, not clean code, fixed

Comment: @the4kman: The linked question is about Qt/QML. You could try to show how to force Qt using the right iOS-keyboard though. There seems to be a problem mapping the `Qt.ImhFormattedNumbersOnly` to the right iOS virtual keyboard. It might be a bug from Qt or from Apple. I would try to file a bugreport there.